Why the tailwind CSS flex box is rendering like this?
Rendered output
<div className="flex flex-col">
  <div className="w-full">
    <p className="text-7xl">Skills</p>
  </div>
  <div className="flex flex-col md:flex-row">
    <div>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem
        labore consectetur, adipisci dicta illum ratione aperiam recusandae
        perferendis. Corporis nihil commodi in! Pariatur, molestias
        similique officiis ad quis impedit dolore.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <Orbit items={orbitItems} size="text-4xl" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

I expected something the output to be something like this:
Title
Lorem ipsum ....                                                            Orbit

It seems like the flex-col class name may not be applying. Consider checking the file this code is in is covered by the content file globs.

There's definitely some other underlying issue here. use browser's inspect feature to see the applied styles on the div.

@ahsan I did inspect the code in browser, the flex-col is in the code, but not rendered

className="" is not a valid attribute of html, you want class=""

Probably using react
